# keep a connection alive in android with a good battery consumption

Tags: android, service, background

I am trying to develop a chat application for android using `Ejabberd` and `XMPP ( smack library )`.
it is needed to keep connection alive to server to notify for new messages and other new activities. I used Services to keep my app running in background ( in onStartCommand function I used return `Service.START_STICKY)`.

I have some problems with this setup,

> 1- Extreamly high battery usage
>
> 2- Services are not allowed in Android O ( It is possible to use 
>      ContextCompat.startForegroundService and use notification, but it is annoying 
>      somehow)

So is there any better solution beside using Services ?

PS. We cant use google services like `GCM`. ( Ejabberd and Android app are not connected to internet(localy) )

In summery:
Problem : keep a connection alive in background with a good battery consumption

challenges :

> 1- Services are not allowed in Android O 
>   2- cant use google services like GCM

Platform:

> XMPP protocol, Ejabberd Server, Smack Library

Comment: You can fire alarm with pendingIntent using AlarmManager to check that your service is running or not . If not then you can start your service again. this will help you  -> `https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#type`

Comment: We can not start service when app is in background in android o and above .